# Test Ruby-on-Rails controller with RSpec and different route name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a Rails model named `Xpmodule` with a corresponding controller `XpmoduleController`.

```
class XpmoduleController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @xpmodule = Xpmodule.find(params[:module_id])
  end

  def subscribe
    flash[:notice] = "You are now subscribed to #{params[:subscription][:title]}"
    redirect_to :action => :index
  end
end
```

The original intent was to name the model `Module` which for obvious reasons doesn't work. However I still want to have the URLs look like `/module/4711/` therefore I added this to my `routes.rb`:

```
map.connect '/module/:module_id', :controller => 'xpmodule', :action => 'index'

map.connect '/module/:module_id/subscribe', :controller => 'xpmodule',
  :action => 'subscribe'
```

Now I want to test this controller with Rspec:

```
describe XpmoduleController do
  fixtures :xpmodules
  context "index" do
    it "should assign the current xpmodule" do
      xpm = mock_model(Xpmodule)
      Xpmodule.should_receive(:find).and_return(xpm)
      get "index"
      assigns[:xpmodule].should be_an_instance_of(Xpmodule)
    end
  end
end
```

for which I get `No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"xpmodule"}`. Which of course is sort-of right, but I don't want to add this route just for testing purposes. Is there a way to tell Rspec to call a different URL in `get`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Head, meet wall, Wall, meet head. *bang*.

Not getting an answer on SO is a sure sign that I should try harder. Therefore I added the `/xpmodule` route explicitly to the `routes.rb`. Just to notice that the tests are still failing. To cut a long story short:

```
it "should assign the current xpmodule" do
  xpm = mock_model(Xpmodule)
  Xpmodule.should_receive(:find).and_return(xpm)
  get "index", :module_id => 1
  assigns[:xpmodule].should be_an_instance_of(Xpmodule)
end
```

is the solution.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell you're testing controller action and not routing to that action. These are two different things!

Try this for starters:

```
it "should map xpmodules controller to /modules url" do
  route_for(:controller => "xpmodule", :action => "index").should == "/modules"
end
```

Apply for other actions as well. If you want to do a reverse routing (from url to controller/action) then do this:

```
it "should route /modules url to xpmodules controller and index action" do
  params_from(:get, "/modules").should == {:controller => "xpmodules", :action => "index"}
end
```

Comment: See my answer, I just wasn't calling the action with the right parameters.